# How to get non windows8 chrome back

Tags: windows-8, google-chrome

I'm running Windows 8 and Chrome.  I recently clicked on the Run Chrome in Windows 8 mode.  I want to switch it back but I can only see a partial screen.  I can't get to the "tools" part of the screen that's usually on the far right.  How can I see the full screen so I can get to the tools section?

Answer (score 0):

Zoom out. (Shift/scroll-wheel back).

Answer (score 0):

Please try the below

- [image] + <kbd>R</kbd> -> regedit
- Browse too: `HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Google\Chrome\Metro`
- Edit the `launch_mode` value and set it to **1** instead of 0.